# Specify the difference between initializing a class With and Without a Reference

Tags: java, javafx, memory, memory-management

I am wondering about the specified benefit of using classes with and without a reference, down to the computer science level regarding to how much space it takes within memory. 
Consider the given situation:
You have a Button Object, that uses a class to specify it's size, color, basic looks, style etc. 
This class has a return method, that require a button object and will return a button object. 
This class will be named: ButtonSpecs
(Method within object below)

```
public Button setButton(Button button)
{
        button.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        button.setOpacity(0.5);
        return button;
}
```

Scenario 1:

```
Button but1 = new Button("Button1");
but1 = new ButtonSpecs().setButton(button);

Button but2 = new Button("Button1");
but2 = new ButtonSpecs().setButton(button);
```

Scenario 2:

```
ButtonSpecs setspecs = new ButtonSpecs();
button1 = setspecs.setButton(button1);
button2 = setspecs.setButton(button1);
```

Part from the clear line difference in code use itself, I am wondering if the use of memory will increase with scenario 1, because of the continuous creation of new ButtonSpecs objects that will only be used once with no reference, than with scenario 2 where one object is created with reference.

As the ButtonSpecs object only will be used "Once" per object and will never be referred to again, there is no need to create an object with a reference unless it has memory benefits.

Comment: I find both those scenarios confusing, since they apparently require a button before you can create a button -- (1) ```button = new Button(); button = something(button)```, and (2) ```button1 = something(button1)```.

Comment: I suppose you could call it a Accessor-method if you  look at it from a theoretical perspective. The method itself will & have to return a button object. Consider having a set of 20 buttons you want to change the look of, using this methods on each of them will create equal buttons when it comes to pure visuals.

Note that I just use Button as an example, the core question comes to memory usage with object creation.

Comment: The pattern I'd implement would be: ```Button b = new Button(myButtonStyle)``` or else ```Button b = myButtonStyle.createButton()```.

Comment: An analysis of this for java is almost impossible: Afaik it's not defined how exactly the bytecode produced for this code needs to look, just some constraints. Furthermore even if you did post the bytecode instructions there is still just-in-time compilation (JIT) involved which may optimize things in an non-predictable way. In this case e.g. theoretically the jit compiler could completely optimize the object creation away, since you never access a member of the object containing the method inside the `setButton` method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two scenarios are actually different in more than one way. Not only are they using `ButtonSpec` differently, scenario 1 creates 2 `Button`s, whereas scenario 2 doesn't create any `Button`s (it does make use of one that is created before hand though).

> I am wondering if the use of memory will increase with scenario 1, because of the continuous creation of new ButtonSpecs objects that will only be used once with no reference, than with scenario 2 where one object is created with reference.

Scenario 1 will indeed use more memory, but the main reason is not that it doesn't have *references*. The usage of memory mainly comes from the objects created, not the references to those objects. The objects are usually much "bigger" than their references.

In Scenario 1, 2 `ButtonSpecs` are created, whereas in Scenario 2, only 1 is, so Scenario 1 will use a little more memory.

Note that whether this amount of memory saved is really *beneficial* is another story, and should be determined with a profiler. You should also consider other factors like style, readability and maintainability (not just memory!) when writing code.

Comment: Ah great, thank you. I figured that the creation of several objects would require more space itself, but maybe it got thrown during the program execution as it is no longer used, therefore save up memory in the long run. 

"Note that whether this amount of memory saved is really beneficial is another story, and should be determined with a profiler. You should also consider other factors like style, readability and maintainability (not just memory!) when writing code."
- I fully agree, just picked this example as a simplified example. :-) 

But thanks for the response!

Comment: @theDev Well, the garbage collector doesn't necessarily collect those objects _immediately_, and the references that you are talking about here are also local variables, so the "long run" argument doesn't really work here.